# Consuming Oracle Data with Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, oracle, web-services, soap

I want to get some data on the server side using OracleClient.
Something like OracleDataReader rdr = OracleDataAccess.ExecuteReader(Conn, sQry);

What is the best way to deliver this data to Silverlight?

I set up a web service I just don't know **the best data structure to package the result set**.

The silverlight CLR can not use the OracleClient DLL, So I can't use any of the typical Oracle result set data structures (DataSet?)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't handle direct data access to your database (it's not always guaranteed that your Silverlight application is going to have proper connectivity to your data source).

Your best bet is to write WCF Services (or any other type of web service) to handle the CRUD operations to Oracle. You can then consume those services from your Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOAP, but if you want something really lightweight, WCF can return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yups correct, SL on the client side no way (it's running in a sandbox), you can just communicatio with a service in the server and from there return the query result (you can run the query just using plain ADO .net or fnacy stuff like ADO .net Entity Framework).

HTH
  Braulio